# Android - Java null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to get data from online database, and show it as an item in Alert Dialog Builder,,

And I've successfully showed my data in alert dialog, and now I want to stored the value of selected items to a variable and shows it on the TextView outside the alertdialog (my current activity)..

But guess there is something wrong with my code, it keeps getting an error of java.lang.nullpointerexception whenever I press the "OK" button inside the alert dialog

This is my code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bBrowseSelectGroup:
        new AttemptViewMyGroup().execute();
        Log.d("flag", "bottom of browse select Group");

        break;
}

public void viewGroup() {
    int success;

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", Username));
        Log.d("Request!", "Starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Success", "Getting array");
            mGroupList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            mGroups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUPS);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < mGroups.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mGroups.getJSONObject(i);
                    String newGroupId = c.getString(TAG_GROUPID);
                    String newGroupName = c.getString(TAG_GROUPNAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_GROUPID, newGroupId);
                    map.put(TAG_GROUPNAME, newGroupName);
                    mGroupList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class AttemptViewMyGroup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(CreateAnnouncementActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loadng...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        viewGroup();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();

        alertDialogBuilder();
        Log.d("flag", "end of post Execute");
    }

}

public void alertDialogBuilder() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Flag", "arrive at alertdialogBuilder");
    final String[] listGroupName = new String[mGroupList.size()];
    final String[] listGroupId = new String[mGroupList.size()];
    final Boolean[] itemsChecked = new Boolean[mGroupList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mGroupList.size(); i++) {
        listGroupName[i] = mGroupList.get(i).get(TAG_GROUPNAME);
        listGroupId[i] = mGroupList.get(i).get(TAG_GROUPID);
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CreateAnnouncementActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Choose Your Group : ");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            stringList.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < listGroupName.length; i++) {
                if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                    groupList.add(listGroupName[i]);
                    stringList.add(listGroupId[i]);
                    itemsChecked[i] = false;
                }

                Log.d("flag", "after for");

            }

            String string = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                string = string + " " + groupList.get(i);
            }
            PostTo.setText(string);
        }
    });
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listGroupName, new boolean[] { false,
            false, false },
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    itemsChecked[which] = isChecked;
                }
            });
    builder.show();
    Log.d("flag", "bottom of alert dialog");
}

}
```

And here is the logcat :

```
01-11 12:56:33.291: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:33.291: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:33.291: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:33.291: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:34.306: D/flag(2034): bottom of browse select Group
01-11 12:56:34.306: D/Request!(2034): Starting
01-11 12:56:34.326: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:34.356: D/ProgressBar(2034): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
01-11 12:56:34.356: D/ProgressBar(2034): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
01-11 12:56:34.356: D/ProgressBar(2034): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
01-11 12:56:34.356: D/ProgressBar(2034): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
01-11 12:56:34.386: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.301: D/Success(2034): Getting array
01-11 12:56:35.321: D/Flag(2034): arrive at alertdialogBuilder
01-11 12:56:35.356: D/AbsListView(2034): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-11 12:56:35.436: D/flag(2034): bottom of alert dialog
01-11 12:56:35.436: D/flag(2034): end of post Execute
01-11 12:56:35.446: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.456: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.461: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.461: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.466: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.576: E/ViewRootImpl(2034): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-11 12:56:35.601: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.606: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.606: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.606: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:35.606: D/TextLayoutCache(2034): Enable myanmar Zawgyi converter
01-11 12:56:36.736: D/flag(2034): after for
01-11 12:56:36.741: D/flag(2034): after for
01-11 12:56:36.741: D/AndroidRuntime(2034): Shutting down VM
01-11 12:56:36.741: W/dalvikvm(2034): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e2bc08)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034): Process: com.thesis.teamizer, PID: 2034
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at com.thesis.teamizer.CreateAnnouncementActivity$2.onClick(CreateAnnouncementActivity.java:231)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
01-11 12:56:36.741: E/AndroidRuntime(2034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is the full code (in case) :

```
package com.thesis.teamizer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CreateAnnouncementActivity extends Activity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

userSessionManager session;
String Username, title, detail, time, expired, url, selectedGroup = "";
Button myButton, browseGroup, bExpired;
ProgressDialog pd;
DatePickerDialog dpd;
EditText announcementTitle, announcementDetail;
Intent intent;
Calendar c;
int flag = 0, mStartYear = 0, mStartMonth = 0, mStartDay = 0;
Database myDb;
TextView PostTo;
AlertDialog dialog;
public ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> groupList = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONParser jsonParser;

public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String TAG_GROUPS = "groups";
public static final String TAG_GROUPID = "groupId";
public static final String TAG_GROUPNAME = "groupName";
public static final String TAG_TOTALROW = "totalRow";

private JSONArray mGroups = null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mGroupList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_announcement_screen);
    sessionDeclaration();
    variableDeclaration();

    browseGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
    // myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    bExpired.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void variableDeclaration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    intent = getIntent();

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDoPostAnnouncement);
    browseGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowseSelectGroup);
    announcementTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_AnnouncementTitle);
    announcementDetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_AnnouncementDetail);
    PostTo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedGroupList);

    bExpired = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bExpiredDate);
}

private void sessionDeclaration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    session = new userSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    Username = user.get(userSessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    myIP ip = new myIP();
    String publicIp = ip.getIp();
    String thisPhp = "viewMyGroup.php";
    url = publicIp + thisPhp;
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bBrowseSelectGroup:
        new AttemptViewMyGroup().execute();
        Log.d("flag", "bottom of browse select Group");

        break;

    case R.id.bDoPostAnnouncement:

        break;

    case R.id.bExpiredDate:
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mStartDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mStartMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mStartYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        bExpired.setText(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1)
                                + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        // ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                    }
                }, mStartYear, mStartMonth, mStartDay);
        dpd.show();

        break;
    }
}

public void viewGroup() {
    int success;

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", Username));
        Log.d("Request!", "Starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Success", "Getting array");
            mGroupList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            mGroups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUPS);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < mGroups.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mGroups.getJSONObject(i);
                    String newGroupId = c.getString(TAG_GROUPID);
                    String newGroupName = c.getString(TAG_GROUPNAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_GROUPID, newGroupId);
                    map.put(TAG_GROUPNAME, newGroupName);
                    mGroupList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class AttemptViewMyGroup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(CreateAnnouncementActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loadng...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        viewGroup();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();

        alertDialogBuilder();
        Log.d("flag", "end of post Execute");
    }

}

public void alertDialogBuilder() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Flag", "arrive at alertdialogBuilder");
    final String[] listGroupName = new String[mGroupList.size()];
    final String[] listGroupId = new String[mGroupList.size()];
    final Boolean[] itemsChecked = new Boolean[mGroupList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mGroupList.size(); i++) {
        listGroupName[i] = mGroupList.get(i).get(TAG_GROUPNAME);
        listGroupId[i] = mGroupList.get(i).get(TAG_GROUPID);
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CreateAnnouncementActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Choose Your Group : ");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            stringList.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < listGroupName.length; i++) {
                if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                    groupList.add(listGroupName[i]);
                    stringList.add(listGroupId[i]);
                    itemsChecked[i] = false;
                }

                Log.d("flag", "after for");

            }

            String string = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                string = string + " " + groupList.get(i);
            }
            PostTo.setText(string);
        }
    });
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listGroupName, new boolean[] { false,
            false, false },
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    itemsChecked[which] = isChecked;
                }
            });
    builder.show();
    Log.d("flag", "bottom of alert dialog");
}

}
```

Comment: And which line is `CreateAnnouncementActivity.java:231`?

Comment: @immibis its this code : if (itemsChecked[i]) {

Comment: check u have intialized mview r not

Comment: Why have you shown your code twice?  One copy has the bug and the other doesn't.  I spent ages looking at the version that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This much shorter program demonstrates the same problem, without as many irrelevant details:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean[] array = new Boolean[10];
        if(array[0]) // <--- NullPointerException HERE
            System.out.println("true");
        else
            System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

Because `array[0]` is a `Boolean` reference (not the primitive type `boolean`), `if(array[0])` invokes auto-unboxing (to convert the `Boolean` to a `boolean`) and is translated to `if(array[0].booleanValue())`.

Elements of reference arrays are initialized to null automatically, so `array[0]` is null at this point.

Then `array[0].booleanValue()` throws a NullPointerException, as you are invoking a method on a null reference.

You might have meant to create a `boolean` primitive array instead of a `Boolean` reference array. Elements of a `boolean` array are initialized to `false`.

Comment: Yes, that is!! I mistook boolean as Boolean.. My god!! Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
final Boolean[] itemsChecked = new Boolean[mGroupList.size()];
```

to

```
final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[mGroupList.size()];
```

The problem with your code is that you make an array of Boolean objects, which will be **nulls** initially. If you change it to primitive boolean it will be okay. You will get an array of booleans initialized to **false**.

Comment: Cool! Yes Boolean and boolean are different. One is an object the other is a primitive.

Comment: But you no need to create array of primitives, if object array expected you can initialize object array indexes

Comment: Yes, if Boolean array is exactly what he needs he can initialize it with a for loop. Otherwise he could simply use Array of boolean primitives and skip initializing in the start. Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

Size of itemsChecked variable is declared in this line

```
final Boolean[] itemsChecked = new Boolean[mGroupList.size()];
```

If `listGroupName.length` is greater than `mGroupList.size()`, it will create an exception. Check both the values and modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `itemsChecked` array first then use it.

```
for(int i=0;i<itemsChecked.lenth;i++)   
itemsChecked[i]=false;
```

Make index true when your condition matches.